# Owl Carousel is not working for my Ajax data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

I have used owl carousel to show my touch point address lists. It works fine when I clicked on the touch point page but when I try to search particular address then it will load all data at once and the carousel doesn't work. You can see the 
[touch point page](http://touch-point.php)

I want to show my data(address) from database using ajax.

Comment: If you are using ajax to fetch data then you need to initialize the owl carousel in the success method of ajax.

Comment: no reproducible code, no error message, no clear statement of what does not work

Answer (score -1):

```
var owl = $("#owl-demo"),
      i = 0,
      textholder,
      booleanValue = false;
      owl.owlCarousel();

//to add the content use additem function

owl.data('owlCarousel').addItem(html);
```